# How do I submit a multipart form with react.js with Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass data from a html form to my handleSubmit function.

My hook declaration:

```
function RegisterForm() {
    const [formData, setData] = useState({
      userName: '',
      email: '',
      passWord: '',
      matchWord: '',
    })
```

my handleSubmit function:

```
function handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(formData)
  }
```

My form:

```
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <label htmlFor="userName">Username: </label>
              <input autoComplete="off"
                    className="form-control"
                    type="text"
                    name="userName"
                    value={formData.userName}
                    onChange={handleChange}></input>
              <label htmlFor="email">Email: </label>
              <input autoComplete="off"
                    className="form-control"
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    value={formData.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}></input>
              <label htmlFor="passWord">Password: </label>
              <input autoComplete="off"
                    className="form-control"
                    type="password"
                    name="passWord"
                    value={formData.passWord}
                    onChange={handleChange}></input>
              <label htmlFor="matchWord">Repeat Password: </label>
              <input autoComplete="off"
                    className="form-control"
                    type="password"
                    name="matchWord"
                    value={formData.matchWord}
                    onChange={handleChange}></input>
              <br></br>
              <button className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </form>
```

If I just submit nothing to the form this is the console output:

{userName: "", email: "", passWord: "", matchWord: ""}

This is expected. If I submit just a userName this the console output:

{userName: "Foo", email: "", passWord: "", matchWord: ""}

This is expected.

If I submit any other combination of inputs the console logs nothing. No output at all. Not expected.

My expectation is that I should be able to fill out all the fields of the form and those values will be displayed by console.log(formData) inside the handleSubmit function upon submitting the form.

I've tried deleting various fields in the form. The result is that console.log(formData) will always display the value of the first field. If any other field is supplied with a value and submitted, nothing at all will be logged, not even the first field.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have solved my problem. If I change the email field to type="text", everything works as expected. type="email" does not seem to be recognized by JSX. I'm going to leave my question up, for others. Would be interested to know more about what input types are valid for JSX.

Comment: May I know what your `handleChange` function looks like?

Comment: ` function handleChange (event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    setData({...formData, [name]: value})
  }` I noted above I solved my own problem though. It appears, from my perspective, that JSX doesn't support the type="email" html prop.